# div overlaps on smaller screen resolution

Tags: html, css

Hi I am having trouble getting a `div` to stay in place when the window is resized. It overlaps the content div when its made smaller.

```
#content
{
  width: 70%; 
  height: 800px;    
  margin-top: 50px;     
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 30px;        
}

#login
{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #4A4344;
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  text-align: center;       
}
```

I tried to set the values to `em` and percentages but I cannot seem to get it working.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, the two `div` tags overlap on my screen even when it's maximized. You want them not to overlap regardless of the screen size?

Comment: Yes thats what I want. It must be because am using high screen size, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the content div's width is set to 70% of the browser's window, and will ignore the login div entirely. Try instead to float **both** the elements. If you set both element's css to `float: right;`, put the login before your content in the html, and remove the width property from the content's css, then it should view how you want it.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, but how can I set the width of the content div as it is only as large as the content inside.

Comment: a standard method is to put them both in a fixed div. If you look at this site (stackOverflow), you will see whitespace on either side. If you create div called container with a set width (such as 960px), and give it margin: 0 auto;. you would then nest your html as follows:
<div id="container">
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="login"></div>
</div>

Does that answer your question ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try white-space: nowrap

Comment: Two more: float the main div also, or clear: left on the login div